# Regex to redirect a simple URL

Tags: regex, url, redirect

What is the regex to transform any url of the form

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)

to

http://en.wikipedia.org/0.5/wiki/Python_(programming_language).

Basically I would like to identify any url that has wikipedia.org and stick in a "0.5/" right after "wikipedia.org/"

Comment: In which language/tool? This doesn't need any regex just string search/replace can do the job

Comment: Eh, did you remove a tag? I could have sworn that I saw a PHP tag...

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression such as this: `^(.+?wikipedia\.org)(.+)$` and then replace it with `$10.5/$2`.

A sample of the regex is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/kV4aO2/1).

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$url = preg_replace('~^(http://.+?)/~', '$1/0.5/', $url);
```

Using regular expressions for URLs, and doing it right, is not trivial. There are a lot of possible edge-cases in the above regex that are not accounted for.

The [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url) function makes working with URLs less error-prone and it is much easier to understand. I would recommend that you use it, instead of using regex.

Something like this should do it, though you should build the new URL more carefully, checking that what you need is in the array, and that you add other stuff not included below (such as the query string, if it should be there).

```
$version = '0.5';
$parts   = parse_url($url);
$newUrl  = "{$parts['scheme']}://{$parts['host']}/{$version}{$parts['path']}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are made for pattern matching and do not have the functionality to replace strings out of the box.

However, many RegEx implementations have substitution available.

In Python, that would be `re.sub()`

```
>>> import re
>>> url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)"
>>> re.sub("wikipedia.org","wikipedia.org/0.5", url)
'http://en.wikipedia.org/0.5/wiki/Python_(programming_language)'
```

However, for your usage situation, you do not need to use the RegEx library for the substitution because it's no different than a single string substitution.

```
>>> url.replace("wikipedia.org", "wikipedia.org/0.5")
'http://en.wikipedia.org/0.5/wiki/Python_(programming_language)'
```

If the reason you are turning to regular expressions is to make sure you're only matching valid URLs, you could try to match the string beforehand with a URL pattern

```
>>> is_wikipedia_url = re.compile(r"https?://.*wikipedia.org/(?!0.5).*")
>>> url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)"
>>> is_wikipedia_url.match(url) is not None
True
>>> url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/0.5/wiki/Python_(programming_language)"
>>> is_wikipedia_url.match(url) is not None
False
```

In this case, the pattern is `https?://.*wikipedia.org/(?!0.5).*`, where

- `https?://` matches either `http://` or `https://`,
- `.*wikipedia.org/` matches any number of any character followed by `wikipedia.org/`, and
- `(?!0.5)` performs a *negative lookahead assertion*, preventing the URL from matching if `0.5` immediately follows `wikipedia.org/` (because you wouldn't want to replace the URL if it already contains 0.5)

If you're not working in Python, you could also you the stream editor `sed`:

```
$ echo "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)" | sed 's/wikipedia.org/wikipedia.org\/0.5/g'

http://en.wikipedia.org/0.5/wiki/Python_(programming_language)
```